# How to config NGINX with php so as to not be "root" location

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I have Nginx configured to work with AgenDAV and baikal. As long as I use the '/' location, it all works fine. Here is the config for that

```
server {
server_name _;
root /agendav/agendav-2.6.0/web/calendar;

location / {
    # try to serve file directly, fallback to index.php
    try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
}

# optionally disable falling back to PHP script for the asset directories;
# nginx will return a 404 error when files are not found instead of passing the
# request to Symfony (improves performance but Symfony's 404 page is not displayed)
# location /bundles {
#     try_files $uri =404;
# }

location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
    # when using PHP-FPM as a unix socket
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;

    # when PHP-FPM is configured to use TCP
    # fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;

    # optionally set the value of the environment variables used in the application
    # fastcgi_param APP_ENV prod;
    # fastcgi_param APP_SECRET <app-secret-id>;
    # fastcgi_param DATABASE_URL "mysql://db_user:db_pass@host:3306/db_name";

    # When you are using symlinks to link the document root to the
    # current version of your application, you should pass the real
    # application path instead of the path to the symlink to PHP
    # FPM.
    # Otherwise, PHP's OPcache may not properly detect changes to
    # your PHP files (see https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus/issues/126
    # for more information).
    # Caveat: When PHP-FPM is hosted on a different machine from nginx
    #         $realpath_root may not resolve as you expect! In this case try using
    #         $document_root instead.
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
    # Prevents URIs that include the front controller. This will 404:
    # http://example.com/index.php/some-path
    # Remove the internal directive to allow URIs like this
    internal;
}

# return 404 for all other php files not matching the front controller
# this prevents access to other php files you don't want to be accessible.
location ~ \.php$ {
    return 404;
}

error_log /var/log/nginx/project_error.log;
access_log /var/log/nginx/project_access.log;
```

}

Notice that the web "root" is in the "calendar" folder.
I want to change this 'from root /agendav/agendav-2.6.0/web/calendar;' to 'root /agendav/agendav-2.6.0/web/' and then be able to access the php correctly with 'http://localhost/calendar/' instead of 'http://localhost/'

How do I change my nginx config to accomplish that?